# Audio equalizer for audio notification in app - react native iOS

Tags: react-native, expo, equalizer, expo-notifications

In light of my bachelor project i am coding an application where it is optimally possible to alter the notification sounds played in the app. In that regard i was wondering if there are any equalizer plug-ins/modules available for react native that fulfills this?

[image]

The picture above shows the wanted functionality